# What is the difference between AWS Kinesis and EventBridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, data-stream, aws-event-bridge

I'm an AWS noob, I'm trying to figure out what the difference between Amazon's Kinesis Data Stream and EventBridge products. Can someone explain this for someone not familiar with the AWS tech stack?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Kinesis** is a real-time stream processing service. Typically gets used for storing logs or end-user data coming from browser.

**Event bridge** is typically used to reliably communicate between apps / microservices, so it's quite similar to SQS, but has some added features.

Differences between SQS and Event Bridge are explained in the post below:
https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/cjnw2l/what_makes_eventbridge_different_than_sqs_and/

Comment: Isn't EventBridge more like SNS? AFAIK, messages don't get retained in a queue, like SQS. My understanding is that EventBridge offers many better features for delivering messages than SNS.